# Function call in onInput in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a function in Javascript to convert a repeated string to a proper formatted string.

For e.g. I have text box and I know that only character that can be written here are 'r','a' & 'm',(combination of small or capital letters) What i want is after every 'ram' written, I convert it to राम and I want to do that after the 3 characters are written .

Below is the code I'm using in a fucntion

text = text.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,''); //removes whitespace from front and end

```
 var count_array = text.split(" ");

 for(var j = 0; j < text.length ; j++) 
        { 
            if ((text[j]+ text[j+1] + text[j+2] == "RAM") || (text[j]+ text[j+1] + text[j+2] == "ram")  || (text[j]+ text[j+1] + text[j+2] == "Ram") || (text[j]+ text[j+1] + text[j+2] == "RAm") || (text[j]+ text[j+1] + text[j+2] == "rAm") || (text[j]+ text[j+1] + text[j+2] == "raM") || (text[j]+ text[j+1] + text[j+2] == "rAM")  || (text[j]+ text[j+1] + text[j+2] == "राम"))
            { 
               document.getElementById("ramnaam_type").value =  document.getElementById("ramnaam_type").value + "राम";

            } 
        }
```

But this is allowing me to add only string in the text box RAM ,i cannot type after it.
I'm calling the function in HTML text box on onKeyDown event.
Any help will be appreciated for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of comparing with lowercase - ram

```js
function validate(event){
  if(event.target.value.length === 3){
      event.target.value = event.target.value.toLowerCase() === 'ram' ? "राम": '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onInput="validate(event)">
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/moMWgO

Comment: Thanks for your resolution but it converts only first entry,if i right "ram ram ram ram" it would convert only the first entry how to loop between the entries again n again so that the next entries also change to राम

Comment: Use event.target.value%3 ===0 for multiples of 3 and use replace to change string 'ram' with event.target.value = event.target.value.replace('ram', 'RAM')